# If $(t_n u_n-t_m u_m)(u_n-u_m) \le 0$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb N$, then $(u_n)$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

I'm trying to solve below exercise, i.e.,

> Let $(u_n) \subset \mathbb R$ and $(t_n) \subset \mathbb R_{>0}$ such that $(t_n)$ is non-decreasing. Assume that
> $$
> (t_n u_n-t_m u_m)(u_n-u_m) \le 0
> \quad \forall m, n \in \mathbb N.
> $$
> Then $(u_n)$ is convergent.

1. Could you have a check on my below attempt?
2. Is there a more direct approach?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

---

We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (t_{n+1} u_{n+1}-t_n u_n)(u_{n+1}-u_n) \le 0 \\
\iff & (u_{n+1}-u_n)^2 \le \frac{t_{n} - t_{n+1}}{t_{n+1}} (u_{n+1}-u_n) u_n.
\end{aligned}
$$

If $t_{n} - t_{n+1}=0$ then $u_{n+1} = u_n$. Let $t_{n} - t_{n+1}<0$. Because $(t_n)$ is non-decreasing, $\frac{|t_{n} - t_{n+1}|}{t_{n+1}} \le 1$ and thus $|u_{n+1}-u_n| \le  |u_n|$. We have three cases, i.e.,

1. If $u_n=0$ then $u_{n+1}=0$.
2. If $u_n>0$ then $u_{n+1} \le u_n$. On the other hand, $|u_{n+1}-u_n| \le  |u_n|$. So $0 \le u_{n+1} \le u_n$.
3. If $u_n<0$ then $u_{n+1} \ge u_n$. On the other hand, $|u_{n+1}-u_n| \le  |u_n|$. So $u_n \le u_{n+1} \le 0$.

It follows that

- if $u_0=0$, then $u_n=0$ for all $n$.
- if $u_0>0$, then $(u_n) \subset \mathbb R_{>0}$ is decreasing.
- if $u_0<0$, then $(u_n) \subset \mathbb R_{<0}$ is increasing.

Thus $(u_n)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Instead of taking absolute values one can also rewrite the given inequality as
$$
 t_n u_n^2 + t_m u_m^2 \le (t_n + t_m) u_n u_m \, ,
$$
which implies that $u_n$ and $u_m$ are both zero or both positive or both negative, so that the $u_n$ are all zero or all positive or all negative.

Then
$$
 0 \le t_{n+1}(u_{n+1}-u_n)^2 \le (t_{n+1}-t_n) u_n (u_n-u_{n+1})
$$
implies that $u_n$ and $u_n-u_{n+1}$ have the same sign, so that (as you correctly concluded) the sequence is identically zero, or positive and decreasing, or negative and increasing.