# Assume $\langle t_n u_n-t_m u_m, u_n-u_m \rangle \le 0$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb N$. How to show that $(u_n)$ is convergent in $\mathbb R^d$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ be the canonical inner product on $\mathbb R^d$. I'm trying to solve below exercise, i.e.,

> Let $(u_n) \subset \mathbb R^d$ and $(t_n) \subset \mathbb R_{>0}$ such that $(t_n)$ is non-decreasing. Assume that
> $$
> \langle t_n u_n-t_m u_m, u_n-u_m \rangle \le 0
> \quad \forall m, n \in \mathbb N.
> $$
> Then $(u_n)$ is convergent in $\mathbb R^d$.

I'm able to solve the exercise in case $d=1$. My [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686566/if-t-n-u-n-t-m-u-mu-n-u-m-le-0-for-all-m-n-in-mathbb-n-then-u-n) relies on the ordering of $\mathbb R$.

> Could you elaborate on how to tackle the case $d > 1$?

Comment: by C-S and from the $d=1$ version, you get $\|u_n\|$ is bounded, monotonic and so convergent. That should probably help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more general result actually holds, i.e.,

> Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $(u_n) \subset H$ and $(t_n) \subset \mathbb R_{>0}$ such that $(t_n)$ is non-decreasing. Assume that
> $$
> \langle t_n u_n-t_m u_m, u_n-u_m \rangle \le 0
> \quad \forall m, n \in \mathbb N.
> $$
> Then $(u_n)$ is convergent in $H$.

**Proof** We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle t_{n+1} u_{n+1}-t_n u_n, u_{n+1}-u_n \rangle &\le 0 \\
\iff  |u_{n+1}-u_n|^2 &\le \frac{t_{n+1} - t_n}{t_{n+1}} \langle u_n, u_n-u_{n+1} \rangle \\
\implies  |u_{n+1}-u_n|^2 &\le \langle u_n, u_n-u_{n+1} \rangle \qquad (1) \\
\iff |u_{n+1}|^2 - 2 \langle u_n, u_{n+1} \rangle +  |u_n|^2 &\le |u_n|^2 - \langle u_n, u_{n+1} \rangle \\
\iff |u_{n+1}|^2 &\le \langle u_n, u_{n+1} \rangle \qquad (2)\\
\implies |u_{n+1}|^2 &\le |u_n| | u_{n+1}| \\
\implies |u_{n+1}| &\le |u_{n}|.
\end{aligned}
$$

This implies $(|u_n|)_n$ is non-increasing and thus convergent. From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
|u_{n+1}-u_n|^2 &\le \langle u_n, u_n-u_{n+1} \rangle \\
\iff |u_{n+1}-u_n|^2 &\le |u_n|^2- \langle u_n,u_{n+1} \rangle \\
\implies |u_{n+1}-u_n|^2 &\le |u_n|^2- |u_{n+1}|^2. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Because $(|u_n|^2)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, so is $(u_n)_n$. This completes the proof.

Comment: This is very nice! Just one remark: Shouldn't it be *“..., so is $(u_n)_n$.”* at the end, without the absolute value?

Comment: @MartinR You're right! It should be "..., so is $(u_n)_n$". Thank you so much!